# How to use typeof for generic argument value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to define an interface where I pass a generic argument, then use the passed value and it's type at the same time.

This is similar to what I want to accomplish:

```js
interface ComponentProps<T extends new (...args: any) => any> {
  params: ConstructorParameters<typeof T>[0]
  onSubmit: (op: T) => void
}
```

Which gives this error because the argument is a value:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

I can define this interface and use it as:

```js
interface ComponentProps<T> {
  onSubmit: (op: T) => void
}

type CustomComponentProps = ComponentProps<ClassA> // I can directly pass the class
```

or

```js
interface ComponentProps<T extends new (...args: any) => any> {
  params: ConstructorParameters<T>[0]
}

type CustomComponentProps = ComponentProps<typeof ClassA> // I need to pass typeof the class
```

It's probably a simple issue which I couldn't figure out yet, but is it possible to pass the class itself as a generic argument and then get its type inside the interface without needing to pass them separately as `ComponentProps<ClassA, typeof ClassA>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to pass the class itself as a generic argument and then get its type inside the interface without needing to pass them separately

You can use [InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) to get the instance type of a class type:

```
class ClassA {
  constructor(public a: string) { }
}

interface ComponentProps<T extends new (...args: any) => any> {
  params: ConstructorParameters<T>[0]
  onSubmit: (op: InstanceType<T>) => void
}

declare const props: ComponentProps<typeof ClassA>
props.params // params: string
props.onSubmit(new ClassA("foo") ) // onSubmit: (op: ClassA) => void
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=69&pln=10&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QILQN4ChrWAewHYQBcAnAV2AOyIAoAHEgIxAEthowAuaQop3AcwCUqaAF80YtLwIBTIgDMwwaXGwBbGnmm4CABSLYaEADwAVaNIAeM3ABMYuaQHdoVAHTuwRPhE5hcATyEAXgA+NgCw9EwaTzBVHxV8YjIKIh1Y1WkZImMTEIBtAAYAXQxoPABlBlUmAk4qA04ASSS-JRN-GmlTEOCwgDdsJhtxNDQbaVBPZRwk6Bp9Q05YNQ0HbT0DYwJO6Ww5OAQIRBC0Ba3XGKI4mAB6W-mMhO5ePjPFiFdK6tqqB2d4JBjlQAERybDYEFCIT3cq4Kr0Gp1FyNQ5AxB9aCDYZAA)

Comment: Thank you very much. `InstanceType` is what I needed. Sometimes it's hard to find about the utilities of typescript in Google or I don't use the right keywords to look for them. :)